# 'make' mdrpdt(a software) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, makefile

```
jcykdeMacBook-Pro:mdrpdt-2.0.1.21 jcyk$ make
Building bin/lib/serial/APPLE-64bit/g++/libutility.a 
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fforce-addr' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]
clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make[1]: *** [../../build/utility/serial/APPLE-g++/64bit/release/application.o] Error 1
make: *** [bin/lib/serial/APPLE-64bit/g++/libutility.a] Error 2
```

I got mdrpdt from http://ritchielab.psu.edu/software/mdr-download.
how can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to remove `-fforce-addr` from the invocation of `clang`, see example [here](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/svn-ports-all/2014-February/047425.html) where `configure` is patched.